# How can i add custom expression functions for Live templates in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

How can add new custom functions for Live Templates in Idea Intellij.

For example i need a custom function which can convert a live template variable from Camel Case to Spaced.
i.e in Live Template on variable has to be inserted at multiple places with & without space.

Eg.   "MyVar" and "My Var". So i want to insert an expression to convert 'MyVar' to 'My Var'.

No expression available by default can be used for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is OpenAPI for providing Live Template functions. One can create IntelliJ IDEA plug-in that will add more functions.

See the [Macro](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/6132bed37a6936e3a780f34aeff769d7f876ccbe/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/template/Macro.java) abstract class. Plug-in should define extension point, like this one:

```
<liveTemplateMacro implementation="com.intellij.codeInsight.template.macro.CapitalizeMacro"/>
```

Search [IntelliJ IDEA Community](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) code base for sample implementations.

Comment: Thanks a lot i was able to make it work by extending MacroBase i.e. Parent of Capitalize Macro.

Comment: so if I create one of these. how do i add it to phpstorm?

Comment: @Artistan look new answer

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @CrazyCoder answer , I will show my code how I added the custom expression to live templates.

1. Creating a Plugin Gradle Project
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/creating-plugin-project.html

If you have error like `Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.`

you should open `Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle` select Gradle JVM to you have installed version

2. Create your own class like this:

```
package com.xxxx.yourPackage;

import com.intellij.codeInsight.template.*;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNls;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

public class MyLiveTemplateExpression extends Macro {


    @Override
    public @NonNls String getName() {
        return "MyLiveTemplateExpression";
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable Result calculateResult(Expression @NotNull [] params, ExpressionContext context) {
        return new TextResult("测试自己的宏");
    }
}
```

In this code the method `getName` will return a string name which will be shown in `live-templates`
[image]

3. edit `plugin.xml` add liveTemplateMacro tag into **extensions** tag, like this:

```
<liveTemplateMacro implementation="com.xxxx.yourPackage.yourClass"/>
```

In my case implementation value is `com.xxxx.cusomLiveTemplate.MyLiveTemplateExpression`

4. Select right sidebar `Gradle` to build `jar`
   [image]
5. open `Perference -> plugins`  click setting icon and choose `install from disk` to install plugin
6. you can use this expression now

Because I am a frontend developer, I do not how to write java code... so the code is not strong, I really hope some javaer can edit this answer or tell me how to write more better!

Sorry for my poor English, Hope someone can edit it and make it more easy to understand