# How to use variable value in live templates in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I want to create live template for setter.

I've created this template
[image]

How can I use value of **par** variable to generate value of **var** variable? Basically, I want to avoid redundancy here and put name of variable only once and other one will be generated automatically by some algorithm.

**UPDATE**

I want to clarify a little bit what I want to achieve.

Suppose I want to create setter with name **setTime** which has parameter **time**.

```
public void setTime(long time)
{
    // ...
}
```

I don't want to type *"time"* twice - capitalized and non-capitalized. I want to type just parameter name so method name will be generated automatically.

**UPDATE (Answer)**

Turned out that variable order is important. This is final result of what I want

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `soutv` as an example, notice how it defines a copy of a variable:

[image: copy]

It's also possible to define custom expression for live templates via plugins or Groovy code:
[How can i add custom expression functions for Live templates in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12156205/104891).

Comment: But how can I combine two functions in Expression field? Suppose I enter *var* variable from my template and I want my *par* variable be lowercase. I see *decapitalize* function. I tried to put **decapitalize(variableOfType(""))** inside Expression, but it didn't work.

Comment: I've tried `capitalize(variableOfType(""))` and it worked for `soutv` template: `EXPR` defined from `test` became `Test`.

Comment: Do you mean, that you typed *"test"* only once and whole line became *"System.out.println("Test = " + test);"*?

Comment: I didn't type anything, `test` was taken from the variable name above `String test = "";` using `variableOfType("")` and transformed to `Test` with `capitalize()`, so it became `System.out.println("Test = " + Test);` as `EXPR_COPY` = `EXPR` in this example.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, [this works fine for me](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/3196/20121227203707.png). `set`, `Tab`, type `long`, `Tab`, type `time`, you should get `public void setTime(long time) {...};`

Comment: Is it possible to use the same for JavaScript?