# How to complete variable names inside a string in IntelliJ Idea live templates?

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

Migrating from Eclipse where doing this was a breeze. One of the most common templates I used was logging the value of last used variable.

E.g.

```
String foo="bar";
```

log tab>

->

```
String foo="bar";
log.debug("foo:{}",foo);
```

I tried using:

```
log.debug("$var$:{}",$var);
```

with both `complete()` and `completeSmart()` as variable types, but they both failed miserably, i.e. did not provide any sane autocomplete suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [How to use variable value in live templates in Intellij IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053301/how-to-use-variable-value-in-live-templates-in-intellij-idea)

In short: LOGGER.debug("$VAR_COPY$: {}", $VAR$); and define first VAR: variableOfType(Type), default "expr" and next $VAR_COPY$ escapeString(VAR) and skip if defined true. Tested with Idea 15.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

1) log.debug("$EXPR_COPY$:{}",$EXPR$);

2) moving EXPR before EXPR_COPY

3) setting EXPR type as completeSmart()

4) setting EXPR_COPY as escapeString(EXPR)